# Menu for specific user

Tags: menus

I'm new in wordpress. I want to hide/show some menus of my main menu according to the user. I mean I want to add some conditions for each menu but I don't know how to do it, if it's possible

Comment: Share what you've tried till now. Give us some codes, so we can understand this properly.

Comment: I'm building a website, there is some user type like student, professor, ... and in wordpress, as I know, the menu is created in admin dashboard and I think it is static (correct me if I'm wrong), then I want to make it dynamic (add menu in code so that I can make some conditions), I've no code about this because I don't know where to do it.

Comment: If you don't know where to start I suggest using a search engine and finding a tutorial that you can understand. [This one](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-conditional-menus-to-wordpress/) looks good, for example.

Comment: User type means "User Role". I mean the student, professor are the user roles, right ? @Dina

Comment: yes that's it, but I don't want to confuse default wordpress user roles (suscriber, ...) with these roles :) @the_dramatist

Comment: Have look on my answer. @Dina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think you need to hide or show the menu items based on ***"User Role"***. So here a possible solution would be creating menus for each roles and showing them by condition based on ***"User Role"***. Here is the code-

```
function the_dramatist_menu_change( $args = '' ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( in_array('your-user-role', $current_user->roles) ) {
        $args['menu'] = 'Menu 1'; // Menu name as string
    } else {
        $args['menu'] = 'Menu 2'; // Menu name as string
    }
    // Add more else if condition based on your user roles.
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'the_dramatist_menu_change' );
```